# Can't delete old TimeMachine backup

Tags: terminal, time-machine, macos

In terminal, trying to do the following:

```
$ sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/BACKUP/Backups.backupdb/lappy/2014-11-02-005458/
Deleting: /Volumes/BACKUP/Backups.backupdb/lappy/2014-11-02-005458
```

I get the following error:

```
Error (-36) deleting: /Volumes/BACKUP/Backups.backupdb/lappy/2014-11-02-005458
Error (512) re-linking Latest for machine directory: /Volumes/BACKUP/Backups.backupdb/lappy
Total deleted: 8.0K
```

Is there another way I can delete old backup files to release disk space?

And Time Machine window shows

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8597674:

> Add your Terminal app (i.e. Terminal.app or iTerm.app) to your list of apps for full disk access in Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way to delete old Time Machine backups.

1. Enter Time Machine (browse your backups).
2. Go back in time to the date that you want to delete.
3. Right click on the folder of the date you want to delete, and choose Delete Backup

Here is a screenshot to help explain:
[image]

Comment: Can you make the image bigger so it's visible?

Comment: @qazwsx Image fixed! It's now visible

Comment: Does this only delete the backup of that specific folder, or does it also delete the backups of all contained sub-folders?

Comment: @FlyingTrashcan when choosing just the "Delete Backup" option it delete the entire backup of all folders/files from that specific time. When choosing to "Delete all backups of "Folder"" it affects ALL of your backups of that specific folder.